# angular: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valueChanges')

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My application allows the user to dynamically generate one or more identical forms that are stored in a FormArray (children) like this:

```
  protected buildForm(): void {
    // Form controls
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      birthDatePartner: [''],
      childrenNumber: ['', [Validators.required]],
      childrenNumberUnder25: [0, [Validators.required]],
      children: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      haveChild: ['no']
    });
```

Each form has a name field and a date field that corresponds to each child of the user. I want to observe the changes in the date field with the observable valueChanges to integrate an error message in case of incorrect entry of the date, but I encounter the following error message:

*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valueChanges')*

Here is the function that creates the form when the user clicks on a button

```
public addChild(addNewBlock: boolean = false): void {
// Do some stuff....
    const child = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstNameChild: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexUtils.identityRegex)]],
      birthDateChild: ['', [Validators.required, reqDateBeforeToday]]
    });
      this.children.push(child);

    this.form.controls.birthDateChild.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000)) // ERROR AT THIS LINE !
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));

// Do some stuff....
  }
```

how do I remove this error?

Thanks for your help*

Comment: Your form doesn't have a birthDateChild control, so `this.form.controls.birthDateChild` is undefined.

Comment: thanks, I'm so stupid, I replaced by child.controls.birthDateChild.valueChanges...

Comment: if you're on Angular 14 I recommend typing your forms https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms, we spent years pestering the angular team to get typed forms for this exact reason.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Angular 14, thanks for your advice